# Expected RBRACE, but the bracket is there?

Tags: html, css, parsing, formatting

**".topcontent {
Expected RBRACE at line 97, col 1." came back in the CSS validator that I used (code beautify)**

Has anyone had this happen before? Does anyone know a fix? It has affected about half of my CSS. I apologize if this is a silly question. I'm new to HTML and CSS and I wasn't able to find a specific answer on the forum.

```
  .content {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;

.topcontent {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.bottomcontent {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.postinfo{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.top-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2% 0 2% 3%;
    padding: 2% 3%; 
}

.middle-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding: 2% 3%;
}

.bottom-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding: 2% 3%;
}
/* Body styling ends here */

.mainFooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #666;
    margin: 2% 0;
}

.mainFooter p {
    width: 92%;
    margin: 2% auto;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Thank you guys! If you need additional information, please let me know.

Comment: you forgot to add the ending brace } for .content style.

Answer (score 1):

The `.content` declaration is missing a `}` brace. You can update it as follows --

```
.content {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
```